# Prove the smallest number of vertices in a cubic graph with a bridge is 10.

Tags: graph-theory

Can you please help me with the proving? This is that kind of a graph:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm3X9.png

Comment: Start by cutting the bridge.  What's the smallest graph that can be on either side?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't fully understand you. Can you please give a little bit more extended answer?

Comment: What question are you asking? What I see begins with "Can you please help..." and then has an image - but no question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** Let $G,H$ be the connected components in a cubic graph after you remove the bridge. What is the degree sequence of $G$ and $H$?